# 新規登録時にbuild(ActiveRecord)を用いて、親と関連付ける外部キーを2つセットする方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

## テーブル構成

### Area

| id | name |

### prefectures

| id | area_id | name |

### prefecture_areas

| id | prefecture_id | name |

### spots

| id | prefecture_id | prefecture_area_id | name |

buildを用いて、以下のようにデータを格納したいです。

### areas(地方を管理するテーブル)

```
| id | name | 
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | 近畿 | 
| 2  | 九州 |
```

### prefectures(県を管理するテーブル)

```
| id | area_id | name | 
| -- | ------- | ---- |
| 1  | 1       | 兵庫 |
| 2  | 2       | 沖縄 |
```

### prefecture_areas(県をさらに細分化する必要がある県のみ、県内のエリアを管理するテーブル)

```
| id | prefecture_id | name | 
| -- | ------------- | ---- |
| 1  | 1             | 南部 |
```

### spots(観光地を管理するテーブル)

```
| id | prefecture_id | prefecture_area_id | name   | 
| -- | ------------- | ------------------ | ------ |
| 1  | 1             | 1                  | 姫路城   
| 1  | 2             | NULL               | 美ら海水族館
```

兵庫県は、prefecture_areasを作り、spotsを登録
沖縄県は、prefecture_areasを作らずに、spotsを登録

Modelの定義

```
    class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :prefectures
    end

    class Prefecture < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :prefecture_areas
      has_many :spots

      belongs_to :area
    end

    class PrefectureArea < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :spots

      belongs_to :prefecture
    end

    class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :prefecture
      belongs_to :prefecture_area
    end
```

このModelの定義で、Area から Spot まで同時にbuildし、
spotsに姫路城を入れる際に、以下のようなコードを書きました。
(formは用いずに、保存します。)

```
Area.new(name: '近畿').prefectures.build(name: '兵庫').prefecture_areas.build(name: '南部').spots.build(name: '姫路城').save
```

すると、

```
INSERT INTO `spots` (`name`, `prefecture_area_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('姫路城', 1, '2016-10-23 09:36:13', '2016-10-23 09:36:13')
```

となり、prefecture_idをspotsに入れてくれません。
buildの段階で、spotsに、prefecture_idとprefecture_area_idを同時に入れることは不可能でしょうか？

長くなってしまいましたが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

試してないですけどコールバックで`prefecture`を設定してやればいいような気がします。

```
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :prefecture
  belongs_to :prefecture_area

  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.prefecture = self.prefecture_area.prefecture if self.prefecture_area
    true #nilよけ
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

難しそうに思えます。
prefecture_areas.build(name: '南部') は PrefectureArea のインスタンスを返します。　PrefectureAreaのインスタンスに対する.spots.buildで、Prefectureに対する.spots.buildではないので。
二度に分けるか、全てのPrefectureがPrefectureAreaを持つようにしてSpotのbelongs_to :prefectureを無くすかでは駄目でしょうか